# BehaviorSubject with transformation

Tags: rx-swift

Is there a way to return a transformed BehaviorSubject?

```
class ViewModel {
    let username: BehaviorSubject<String>

    init() {
        // I want username to emit trimmed values...
        username = BehaviorSubject<String>(value: "")
            // ... but map returns an Observable<>, not BehaviorSubject
            .map { $0.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, there is no way to return a transformed BehaviorSubject.

You have to first define the output that you want to affect, then figure out what inputs affect it. The `map` will go between those. So for example:

```
myTextField.rx.text.orEmpty
    .map { $0.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces)
    .bind(to: username)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

If you want username to be the output, or

```
username.asObservable() // I'm not sure if the asObservable() is actually necessary at the moment. Check that.
    .map { $0.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces)
    .bind(to: myLabel.rx.text)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

if you want username to be the input.

To create a `username` just use `let username = BehaviorSubject<String>()`